# Eclipse Java editor text doesn't appear

Tags: java, eclipse, editor

In the java editor of eclipse, source code appears for a second and then disappears. It shows one line or nothing. I have created a new workspace, installed latest JDK, installed Eclipse neon but the problem remains the same. My system has Windows 10.

[image: Java Editor screenshot]

Comment: Why not scroll down? It seems you have a lot of white spaces.

Comment: It seems like that but it has nothing.

Comment: try editing the text color and editor panel color, looks like they are same

Comment: It worked!! when I changed font from Consolas to other. Thank you so much. But I want to work with this default font. Can you tell me any solution of this problem?